# Uncountable sets and interval topology

Tags: general-topology, order-theory

Let be an uncountable well-ordered set $(X,\leq)$. We suppose that exists some $x\in X$ such that $y < x$ for uncountably many values of $y$ and define $x_1$ as the minimum $x\in X$ such that $y < x$ for uncountably many values of $y$. Let be a function $f$ such that $f(x)=0$ for $x\ne x_1$ and $f(x_1) = 1$. For the order topology on $X$ (basic open sets are open intervals), show that f is not continuous, but for every convergent sequence $u_n\to u$ in X, $f(u_n)$ converges to $f(u)$.

Comment: By 'interval topology', do we mean the order topology?

Comment: Also, can you elaborate on the uniqueness of $x$? Supposedly, if nothing is known about $X$, such a requirement is unrealistic (observe that $X+1$ is uncountable as well).

Comment: $x_0$ is the minimum $x$ s.t....? Also know as $\omega_1$.

Comment: For any partially ordered set (X,<), the collection {X} ∪ {{x: x <
y}: y ∈ X} ∪ {{x: x > z}: z ∈ X} is a subbase for a topology on X
called the interval topology.

Comment: The question just said that X is uncountable and to find such a x, guessing the uniqueness stems that x is a least element of some subset of X, other than that I almost, so any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: You do not need the axiom of choice to exhibit an uncountable well-ordered set. Note that we do not attempt to well-order a *given* uncaountable set.

Comment: @Hamish, edit to clarify the minimality condition. Better use the name $\omega_1$.

Comment: Ok, can you give me a reference so I can see how that is proved, or can you outline it for me. Thanks very much, am very interested in looking further into that.

Comment: I can edit your post if you want, but now I'm writing in my smartphone. A bit later I will be in a computer.

Comment: $x$ may not in general be unique (or exist at all) but if there is any such $x$, you can certainly ask for the unique smallest such, which for $X > \omega_1$, is the unique minimal element of the subset of all $x$ having the property that $y<x$ for uncountably many $y$.

Comment: So $\omega_1$ here is just a name and not the ordinal $\omega_1$???

Comment: Please can you unedit the post to the original, as the question asked to find such an x and you give one, so who is right?? this is very confusing

Comment: the original question from Dudley is: Assuming the axiom of choice, there is an uncountable well-ordered
set (X,≤). Show that there is such a set containing exactly one
element x such that y < x for uncountably many values of y. Let
f (x) = 1 and f (y) = 0 for all other values of y ∈ X. For the interval
topology on X, show that f is not continuous, but for every sequence
un → u in X, f (un) converges to f (u).

Answer (score 1):

The image set is discrete, so {1} is open. The inverse image is $\{x_1\}$ that isn't open in the interval topology.

But $f$ is sequentially continuous:

The only interesting case is when $\forall n\in{\Bbb N}:\ u_n<x_1$. For a such sequence, if $\exists l=\lim_{n\to\infty} u_n$, then $l<x_1$. Namely, let be $I_n=\{x\in X\vert x\le u_n\}$ and $I=\cup_{n\in{\Bbb N}}I_n$. $I$ is countable because is a countable union of countable sets (countable choice is required here) and an interval, so $l\le\sup I<x_1$.

Comment: Please can you elaborate a bit more, as am still a bit confused.  So you considered $\omega_1+1$ as it uncountable and any well-ordered uncountable set is order isomorphic to it?  But then how do we know that $\omega_1$ is our unique $x$, as isn't $\omega_1+1$ also order isomorphic to $\omega_1$ which has no top element? please help really confused.  Also do not see how how hint gives $f(u_n)\arrow f(u)$ Please help.

Comment: Is $\omega_1$ the 2nd limit ordinal in you answer or just a variable that like the original x??  Please clarify thanks

Comment: I've edited again your message because the *existence* of your original $x$ can be false. $X$ is *isomorphic* to *some* ordinal ($X$ is well-ordered) $\ge\omega_1$-the-ordinal ($X$ is uncountable) and $>\omega_1$-the-ordinal (because the additional hypothesis). My $\omega_1$=min of $x$... is *like* $\omega_1$-the-ordinal. You can use another name if you like. About the hint for the sequence: you can't have $u_n\to\omega_1$ except if $u_n\ge\omega_1$ for $n$ large enough. Technical name of the essential property: the cofinality of $\omega_1$ is uncountable.